# bash linux - write and read from stdin and stdout

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stdin

I have an application which I can run from the commonand line and it acts like a CLI for me.

However its part of a suite of applications and now I want them all to run on boot up and so they are being started as a service (systemd).

So all my apps includeing my CLI are running great. However I can't see the output of the CLI and I can't send commands to it.

I was using the stdout to print the CLI screen - I guess I can work around this by outputting to a file - but it would be nice to get access to its stdout. The bigger issue is that I can't write to its stdin.

I read this: [writing-to-stdin-of-background-process](https://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process) and tried to `echo -e "command\n" > /proc/.../0`, but nothing happened - I checked the log of my CLI (gets written to a file) and it did not get the input.

I then did a `ls -l` on `/proc/<pid>/fd/` and I notice that `0 --> /dev/null` meaning stdin is linked to /dev/null.

So, how can I get access to its stdin?

Bonus question - is there a way to operate (in the same bash shell) such that I re-direct my stdin to the stdin of this process AND redirect the process stdout to my shell?

Comment: I don't know if it works, but one idea is to create fifo using `mkfifo /tmp/hoo`. And in the systemd file set: `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/your/cli/command < /tmp/hoo'`.
Now if you `echo -e "command\n" > /tmp/hoo"` it should be piped to `/your/cli/command`

Comment: @ymonad I am just testing this on the command line first. When I run `./myapp < /tmp/hoo` (after making the fifo) it does not seem to run the app until I do my first echo command to it. That's quite strange! - but it does start to work after that

Comment: maybe your cli command is not intended to access via stdin. did you checked that `echo 
 command | /your/command` works?

Comment: @ymonad - yes that worked...  Your first idea did work, but the app did not seem to start until the received the first command - and then it ran normally

Answer (score 2):

Find the terminal (pty) that You want to redirect. Example for pty0 redirection can be done via:

```
exec < /dev/pty0  #stdin
exec > /dev/pty0  #stdout
```

Comment: How do you find the /dev/pty?

Comment: Similar You did for background process /proc/<pid>/fd/. So go to active terminal , then do echo $$, that will gives You pid of current shell and if shell is interactive it must have set pty in /proc/<pid>/fd/